# CSRF Token Missing When Posting Request To DVWA Using Python Requests Library

Tags: python, html, post, python-requests

I'm trying to make a program that will allow me to submit username and password on a website. For this, I am using `DVWA`(Damn Vulnerable Web Application) which is running on localhost:8080.
But whenever I try to send post request, it always returns an error.

> csrf token is incorrect

Here's my code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://192.168.43.1:8080/login.php'
data_dict = {"username": "admin", "password": "password", "Login": "Login"}
response = requests.post(url, data_dict)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make GET request for that URL first, and parse the correct "CSRF" value from the response (in this case `user_token`). From response HTML, you can find hidden value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="28e01134ddf00ec2ea4ce48bcaf0fc55">
```

Also, it seems that you need to include cookies from first `GET` request for following request - this can be done automatically by using request.Session() object. You can see cookies by for example `print(resp.cookies)` from first response.

Here is modified code. I'm using BeautifulSoup library for parsing the html - it finds correct input field, and gets value from it.

`POST` method afterwards uses this value in `user_token` parameter.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:

    url = 'http://192.168.43.1:8080/login.php'
    resp = s.get(url)
    parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features="html.parser")
    input_value = parsed_html.body.find('input', attrs={'name':'user_token'}).get("value")
    data_dict = {"username": "admin", "password": "password", "Login": "Login", "user_token":input_value}
    response = s.post(url, data_dict)
    print(response.content)
```

Comment: Will you please tell me how to parse the correct csrf values?..actually i m still a newbie and it would help me a lot

Comment: It worked..although there are some line which i didn't understand but still thank you it means a lot. :)